# Connect to Azure Resource under VPN P2S

Tags: azure, vpn, point

I'm trying to setup a Point-to-Site (P2S) VPN from my Windows 10 machine to my Azure Server and, even successfull connect to the VPN, I cannot connect to the server.

My Azure server has 2 network interfaces:
1st has private IP 10.0.0.5/24 (and an associated Public IP, that allow me to connect with Remote Desktop normally, but off the VPN).
2nd has private IP 10.0.0.4/24, without Public IP. (the other public IP is used with the virtual network gateway to use the VPN).

I've added the net/subnet "172.16.10.0/24" as addresses pool in my virtual network gateway.
* When I connect, an IP /32 address is assignet to my local machine, like 172.16.10.3 / 255.255.255.255, and I can ping 172.16.10.0

(no code to be displayed)

The certificate setting is ok, the connection to the VPN is OK. I only cannot connect to my Azure Server on my second interface 10.0.0.4.

Any idea that I've forgot to do?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean` I only cannot connect to my Azure Server on my second interface 10.0.0.4.` It looks like two NICs in the same subnet, right?

Comment: Nancy, I can connect to VPN, but can't connect to server under VPN.
Yes! The server has two NICs in the same subnet.

Comment: Did you configure the Private IP in the Guest OS level as well as per below article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell#os-config

Comment: Is the Primary NIC accessible ? Try connecting via Layer 4 connectivity like telnet or psping instead of ICMP ping

Comment: Hi msrini-MSIT, you're right! Private IP on Azure local network Gateway has been wrong on setup. I've fixed specifying my local range, but, not only this, it was needed a new route table, associating this with the GatewaySubnet (in the Virtual Network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: My Private IP range on Azure local network Gateway has been wrong on setup. I've fixed specifying my correct local IP range, but, not only this, a new route table was created, associating this with the GatewaySubnet (in the Virtual Network).

Thanks to Nancy Xiong and msrini-MSIT for help.

Comment: You could accept this answer for others reference. (on the left of your reply, there is an option to check mark)

Comment: Ok Nancy! Done!